# Outlook client lost email when changed server on account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm not sure if this is the appropriate forum, so please be gentle. I didn't find a lot of SE forums that came up in a search as having Outlook questions.

My company recently went from using the email provided by their web host to exchange server. I simply changed my existing email account to point to the new server, specifically to avoid losing my old emails. Unfortunately, the first time it synchronized, it deleted all my old conversations. I tried restoring the pst to one from last week, but this didn't work. It seems to remember the new server settings and so it doesn't show the old emails.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an alternate method of getting to your old mailbox, ie, webmail, you should confirm it's there first. If so, add it as a second account in Outlook: File -> Account Settings -> Account Settings -> New. That will start the wizard to add the old account. Until that old account is purged you should have full access to both.

If it's really gone you'll need to get in touch with your admins or the admins of the old web host. The old mailbox might still be there and not accessible while they're wrapping up the migration.

Comment: Please do not post answers where you should be commenting. Answer or ask questions until you get enough rep to leave comments.

Comment: OK. I'm new here. I'm not sure what you're saying. I think I'm answering and I think I'm posting in the right place. I don't even have the rep (50 needed) to comment.

Comment: I see that you're new. No hard feelings. While you have answered, you also asked a question which would generally be asked in a comment before answering. I didn't down-vote or flag your answer, just a friendly tip.

Comment: In this Q&A format, answers are intended to be solutions to the question.  Gathering clarifying information to enable an answer is done in a comment.  So posting an answer that starts with a question gets confusing.  If the question is intended as a qualifier, you could word it "If..." and then the answer, which would be clearer.  The site has a little bit of a learning curve.  :-)

Comment: I can learn! I've read a lot so happy to contribute, too.